# Android Studio 3.1 Logcat prefix not always showing and breaking pretty logger

Tags: android-studio, logcat, android-studio-3.1

Since the new version of Android Studio (3.1) the Logcat window doesn't always show the prefix (`03-28 12:43:01.091 nl.test.app D/log`). I made my own logger, which prints in a pretty way, but this gets broken since some lines are no longer with the same indentation. I'll show an example below.

```
03-28 12:43:01.091 nl.test.app D/log: ╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    ║ [ (TestActivity.kt:33)#OnCreate ] 
    ║ This is my test log
03-28 12:43:01.092 nl.test.app D/log: ║ This is my second test log
    ╚═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

This is how it used to be:

```
03-28 12:43:01.091 nl.test.app D/log: ╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
03-28 12:43:01.091 nl.test.app D/log: ║ [ (TestActivity.kt:33)#OnCreate ] 
03-28 12:43:01.091 nl.test.app D/log: ║ This is my test log
03-28 12:43:01.092 nl.test.app D/log: ║ This is my second test log
03-28 12:43:01.092 nl.test.app D/log: ╚═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: This is the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77305804

Comment: This makes my beautiful logs look like garbage.... :(

Comment: Amazing how such a small change in the log layout makes it so much harder to read. My eyes/brain literally hurt trying to scan the log for what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the issue tracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77305804) it is fixed and is planned for Android Studio 3.2. To quote from the issue tracker:

> This change in behavior was inadvertent and I reverted it. The fix will go out in 3.2.

It does not say when this version will be released. But I'll update my answer as soon as I know.

**Edit**

Android Studio 3.2 is released and my pretty logger is working again!

Answer (score 2):

The observation is correct. In Android Studio 3.1.4 it is also broken. Not only the prefix is not printed always, also complete lines dissappear.

But there is a small workaround:

1. open the Terminal Window in Android Studio
2. start a shell in your target:

   > C:\directory> adb shell
3. in that shell start logcat with grep as filter:

   > device:/ $ logcat | grep
4. than you see all filtered entries with all contents