# How to show logcat header on every line?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I just updated Android Studio to the last stable version 3.1

I noticed that something has changed in the **logcat tab**: in the previous release every line of the logcat started with the header; now the header is printed only at the start of "every group" of logcat messagges.

Android 3.0

[image: example 3.0]

Android 3.1. Look at the debugging lines of OkHttp!

[image: example 3.1]

How to restore the logcat like in Android 3.0?

Comment: this is so much better now :D I hated the header for OkHttp on each line. If you had a big json response, it would've been impossible to copy it without those annoying headers :D

Comment: I'm literally updating cause of this only. I love it :)

Comment: what disturbe me is the identation...

Comment: I have somewhat the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535163/android-studio-3-1-logcat-prefix-not-always-showing-and-breaking-pretty-logger. The annoying part is that in the middle of the json response the header is sometimes still shown. If you look at my post, it's super annoying to read . I would agree if all of the log came with just 1 header, but that's not the case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 3.1 Logcat prefix not always showing and breaking pretty logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535163/android-studio-3-1-logcat-prefix-not-always-showing-and-breaking-pretty-logger)