# How to prevent timestamps in logcats in Android Studio from being stripped?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

When looking at logcats in Android Studio 3.1, sometimes the "metadata" portion of some log lines are omitted. For example, the leading portion gets removed, which might look like:

```
06-06 17:55:39.364 9929-9945/com.ttm.zapp I/com.ttm.zapp:
```

Everything that follows that prefixed data in the log line is printed, however. See the image below for a better example.

[image]

Is this a bug? And if not, is there a way to disable this (what appears to be) "grouping" behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grouped log statements are printed at the same timestamp. If you type `adb logcat` into the terminal, you can see the formatted logs there.

That being said, there is an issue being tracked on Android Studio [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78105884) to make this logcat behavior a configurable option.

Comment: Solved in Android Studio 3.2 I believe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535163/android-studio-3-1-logcat-prefix-not-always-showing-and-breaking-pretty-logger